# Blade engine in Laravel - yield doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have been repeatedly trying to make simple blade template work. This is the code:

**routes.php**

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

**BaseController.php**

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

**hello.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>swag</title>
</head>
<body>

    hello

    @yield('content')

</body>
</html>
```

**content.blade.php**

```
@extends('hello')

@section('content')

<p>content check</p>

@stop
```

When I run this code in a browser, all there is is just hello text I wrote in hello.blade.php, however yield('content') does not display anything and I can't figure out why. I'd appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You created the wrong view. The parent view is `hello`, it doesn't know about `content`. That's why you wrote `@extends('hello')`, that way when you create your `content` view, it will know that it has to extend stuff from `hello`.

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('content');
});
```

Comment: Oh my god thanks, my thought process was, that since I set master view as default, it will check, if anything should be added to it and then display all the yields and includes. Looks like I was wrong, this worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

For all of those struggling with this, make sure that your template php file is name with the blade extension in it, like so: **mytemplate.blade.php**, if you  make the mistake of leaving the .blade extension out, you template will not be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

instead of

```
@extends('hello')
```

in your `hello.blade.php` view file and make sure you have a master layout in your `views/layouts` directory so your `hello.blad.php` will extend the master layout and template will show up.

Actually, your `hello.blade.php` file should be `master.blade.php` and `hello.blade.php` should extend this master layout so `hello.blade.php` should look something like this:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<p>content check</p>

@stop
```

The `master.blade.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>swag</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried that, changed file names, extends, route etc., unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: Try it properly, you probably made mistakes, there is nothing wrong in this answer, if you do it properly it'll work. Also [check the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/templates).

Comment: This is a very difficult to understand explanation of the process that you should replace all `hello` with `master` and all `content` with `hello` in your Blade files, including their file names.